# Python - Pandas: Create new column that is the aggregate sum of another column's group conditional on a date column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, aggregate

Sample Data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 1 | 2022-09-01 |
| John | 0 | 2022-09-02 |
| Bill | 1 | 2022-09-04 |
| Bill | 0 | 2022-09-10 |

I want to create a column where column B is summed based on column A... but only the instances where column C is less than or equal to the current row.

What I Want:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | NEW COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 1 | 2022-09-01 | 0 |
| John | 0 | 2022-09-02 | 0 |
| Bill | 1 | 2022-09-04 | 1 |
| Bill | 0 | 2022-09-10 | 2 |

So the new column is the sum of column B grouped on column A, but it is only summing column B for dates in column C that are prior to the current row. Therefore, in the last row above, Bill has a 2 in the NEW COL because column B is summed for all instances prior to 2022-09-10.

I have my groupby for a basic aggregation:

```
df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].transform(np.sum)
```

But this doesn't take the date into account and I am stuck on whether to use a groupby at all or if I need to use a lambda function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 df['NEW COL'] = (df.groupby('Column A')
                   .apply(lambda x: x[x['Column C'] <= x['Column C']]
                   .sum()['Column B']))
```

Comment: I've tried this and my column is all 0's. Also received this warning: 

"FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction."

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You might want a shifted [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) per group:

```
df['NEW COL'] = (df
   .sort_values(by='Column C')
   .groupby('Column A')['Column B']
   .transform(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))
)
```

Output:

```
  Column A  Column B    Column C  NEW COL
0     Bill         1  2022-09-01        0
1     John         0  2022-09-02        0
2     Bill         1  2022-09-04        1
3     Bill         0  2022-09-10        2
```

##### handling duplicated dates

```
df2 = (df
   .groupby(['Column A', 'Column C'], as_index=False)['Column B'].sum()
   .sort_values(by='Column C')
)
    
out = df.merge(df2.join(df2.groupby('Column A', group_keys=False)['Column B']
                           .apply(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))
                           .rename('NEW COL')
                       ).drop(columns='Column B'),
               on=['Column A', 'Column C'], how='left'
               )
```

Output:

```
  Column A  Column B    Column C  NEW COL
0     Bill         1  2022-09-01        0
1     John         0  2022-09-02        0
2     Bill         1  2022-09-04        1
3     Bill         1  2022-09-10        2
4     Bill         0  2022-09-10        2
5     Bill         1  2022-09-11        3
```

Comment: Would this still work knowing that there will be duplicate values in the date column?

Comment: @Nicholas it depends how you want to handle them, can you update your example?

Comment: I'd prefer to handle it as a strict inequality... if Column C < Column C, then sum the values

Comment: Minor update to avoid the duplicated Column B

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.sort_values("ColumnC").ColumnB.expanding().sum().shift(fill_value=0)
    return dd1

df1.assign(NEWCOL=df1.groupby('ColumnA').apply(function1).droplevel(0)).pipe(print)
```

out：

```
  ColumnA  ColumnB     ColumnC  NEWCOL
0    Bill        1  2022-09-01       0
1    John        0  2022-09-02       0
2    Bill        1  2022-09-04       1
3    Bill        0  2022-09-10       2
```